# Zurb Foundation v5.5.3 accordion not working

Tags: jquery, accordion, zurb-foundation-5

I am using foundation 5.5.3 and I am trying to setup a simple accordion. I setup everything like in the docs (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/accordion.html)

The problem is: I can see that the different categories get the a new class "active" when I click them. They also get aria-expanded="true". However, it does not toggle anything. Moreover, when I click a second time, the class is not removed and aria-expanded stays equal to "true".

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="accordion" id="myAccordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#cat1">Cat 1</a></li>
  <div id="cat1" class="content active">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#cat2">Cat 2</a></li>
  <div id="cat2" class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Here is my js with console output:

```
$(document).foundation({
  accordion: {
    // specify the class used for accordion panels
    content_class: 'content',
    // specify the class used for active (or open) accordion panels
    active_class: 'active',
    // allow multiple accordion panels to be active at the same time
    multi_expand: true,
    // allow accordion panels to be closed by clicking on their headers
    // setting to false only closes accordion panels when another is opened
    toggleable: true
  }
});
$('#myAccordion').on('toggled', function (event, accordion) {
  console.log(accordion);
});
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfm1ssLa/2/

Any help would be greatly appreaciated... Everything I found on the forum was of no help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to wrap the content within the list.

```
<ul class="accordion" id="myAccordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#cat1">Cat 1</a>
    <div id="cat1" class="content active">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#cat2">Cat 2</a>
    <div id="cat2" class="content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code should work.